# Where can I find the source code for the JBoss AS 5 default exception handling JSP?

Tags: jsp, jboss

I have JBoss AS 5. I'd like to see the default JSP that JBoss uses for handling exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JBoss AS uses [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org) as servletcontainer. In Tomcat you can find that code hardcoded(!) in under each [`org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/ErrorReportValve.html). You can find the published source code [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/ErrorReportValve.java.html).

Comment: Good lord, it doesn't even use EL! D: ...I thought it might be Tomcat rather than JBoss; I'm still not 100% on what each thing does.

Comment: JBoss is a full fledged Java EE Application Server. I.e., implementing all parts of the [Java EE API](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/). It uses Tomcat to fill in under each the `javax.servlet.*` parts of the Java EE API and further it uses another 3rd party or inhouse-grown components to fill in the other Java EE API parts.